# Почему не добавились элементы в массив?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

Пытаюсь добавить словари с массив itemsElems:

```
const itemsElems = []
getTable().then(res => {
    res.map( function(elem) { 
        console.log("Elem:", elem);
        itemsElems.push(elem);
    } )
})
console.log("ItemsElems:", itemsElems);
```

Вот это выводится:

```
ItemsElems: []
Editor.jsx:19 Elem: {id: 1, idgovernor: 1, inforegion: "!InfoRegion!", idnews: 1}
Editor.jsx:19 Elem: {id: 2, idgovernor: 2, inforegion: "!InfoRegion!", idnews: 1}
```

Почему список пустой? И почему он вообще первым выводится, если его вывод стоит в конце?

Comment: js ассихронный ...вызвали getTable() и пошли дальше скрипт исполнять, а когда getTable() отработает тогда и встроенный код будет выполнен

Comment: @Volodymyr, как это исправить?

Comment: А ещё на надо так использовать map.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как добавить с помощью response элементы в массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводится первым, потому, что функция getTable() возвращает promise.
Поэтому JS сначала выполняет код который стоит после него.
Чтобы исправить, можно подождать ответа от промиса getTable() через await.
То есть:

```
async function fillArray() {
    const itemsElems = [];    
    let res = await getTable();
    res.map(elem => { 
            console.log("Elem:", elem);
            itemsElems.push(elem);
    });
    console.log("ItemsElems:", itemsElems);
}
```

Comment: @Volodymyr, как это исправить?

Comment: await не будет работать без async функции

Comment: @Vlad Отредактировал

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, можете поподробнее пожалуйста. Если getTable не async то работать не будет? И как понять что async?

Comment: @Vlad async, если при обьявлении функции есть идентификатор async

Comment: @Vlad await же принимает любой асинхронный результат, но при условии что функция асинхронная

Comment: @Vlad таким образом мы делаем асинхронный код, как будто он синхронный